# Atomic update statement with select SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
INSERT stuff
SET computed = 'working'
WHERE id = (SELECT max(id) from STUFF WHERE x = y)
```

I would like to make this statement atomic in SQL Server 2005 SP 1.

Is there a way of doing this without modifying the isolation level?

I need to simulate an insert into a table with an Identity column as the pk. My current table doesn't have an Identity field as the pk but it needs to act like it does. So i need to get the max of the pseudo ID field and add 1 then insert the next row.

Comment: I recommend you flesh out this question with more about what you are expecting, more about the rest of the moving parts of the system (other SQL which will be going on), and more about the goals of the system this is part of.

Comment: I'm confused because it seems like you're trying to simulate IDENTITY behavior with an UPDATE instead of an INSERT.

Comment: @cade roux fixed. Thank you for noticing

Comment: Do you mean to reuse the maximum "identity" value, mean to increment it, or is something stranger going on?  Can rows be deleted from `stuff` or `STUFF`?  Is recycling previous values going to be a problem?

Comment: @HABO I do not plan on re-using max, rows can be deleted, and i am not going to recycle previous values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To lock the value down, one way is to to use SERIALIZABLE isolation level.

```
DECLARE @id int;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
BEGIN TRAN
SELECT TOP(1) @id id from STUFF WHERE x = y ORDER BY id DESC;
INSERT stuff (id, ...) VALUES (@id, ...);
COMMIT
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
```

Make sure to keep it as short as possible.

Comment: modified my question to make it easier understood

Comment: I didnt want to have to wrap it in a serializable tansaction, but I have found any other way of doing this. So thank you for reconfirming

Comment: @gh9 - How did you solve the problem of always assigning a previously unused value even if the last row had been deleted?

Comment: @HABO I think OP meant that deleted values (gaps) won't be re-used, but if the max has been deleted, it's fair game as the new id again.

Comment: Are you sure the SELECT will put the lock correctly?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't add an IDENTITY column, can you make another table which contains an IDENTITY column?  Then simply insert into that table and use the @@IDENTITY in order to insert into the table which needs the sequence.  This technique will remember the last number for you so you don't get any re-used values.

A similar technique is used to simulate Oracle's sequences (which are table-independent) in pre-2012 version of SQL Server.

http://www.sqlmag.com/article/tsql3/simulating-oracle-sequences-in-t-sql-code

You can always throw these sequence tables into a separate schema if you like.